# Using HDMI monitor powered by Nvidia graphics during bitlocker password screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card

To my knowledge, my external HDMI monitor is connected to my laptop through Nvidia graphics card.

But the problem is, it doesn't work during the BitLocker prompt during the system startup. Is it possible to somehow add NVidia drivers to that screen so I can use my external monitor to enter password?

Comment: This should be not a driver problem. AFAIK the Bitlocker prompt still uses the VESA mode which does not require any drivers. Check your BIOS if you can set the external monitor as primary monitor. I assume then also the Bitlocker prompt will be shown on the selected monitor.

Comment: @Robert Unfortunately there is no such setting in BIOS.